# Unable to open ssh of vm instance on GCP : cannot connect to backend (code : 4003)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssh, cloud, virtual-machine, devops

There was recommendation for machine specification modification and so I Reduced the specification of instance.
After that When I am opening SSH of VM instance on GCP it gives me an error as shown in image
[image]

After that tried recommendation and clicked on connect without identity-aware proxy then following error occured
[image]

Although I have allowed default-allow-ssh on port 22 for ingress as it comes by-defualt by gcp.

Also tried some other solutions as previously mentioned of using custom metadata with key 'startp-script' and value as a bash command but that did not work .

What is missing? I have other instances too but i can access ssh of them. There is only 1 instance that is not being accessed.

Comment: Login to the VM using the Serial Port and check [guest environment](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/install-guest-environment#wgei_packages) is working properly, sometime if the guest environment not working then you are not able to access the VM using SSH. Also check port 22 is open or not using 'nmap ip-address -Pn' tool.

Comment: Serial port is also not connecting.

Comment: You need to enable the serial port first.

Comment: VM was corrupted so created a new VM instance using snapshot of corrupted VM

Answer (score 0):

According to [Google Cloud FAQ](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/faq):

> **Error Code 4003**
> This might mean the instance isn't listening on the port you're trying to connect to or the firewall is closed. Either of those issues could also cause the start-up connectivity test to the VM instance to fail.

Check if your [firewall rules](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls) allow SSH connection, you should look for `default-allow-ssh`.

You can also enable serial connection to your virtual machine:

```
gcloud compute instances add-metadata instance-name \ --metadata serial-port-enable=TRUE
```

Connect to the machine:

```
gcloud compute connect-to-serial-port instance-name
```

and check status of ssh service:

```
sudo systemctl status sshd.service
```

If these steps do not resolve your issue, you can follow this guide: [Troubleshooting SSH](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/troubleshooting/troubleshooting-ssh)
I had the same problem couple of times, but they resolved themselves after couple of minutes.

Comment: No, it did not worked. Even serial port is not also connecting.

Comment: Have you tried to follow the documentation and troubleshoot SSH? Could you please update your answer with your steps, commands and outputs?

Comment: My VM Instance was corrupted so created a new VM instance using Snapshot of corrupted vm. This solution was suggested by Google Cloud Support and it worked.